# El codigo no me funciona para la deteccion de huella digital

Tags: arduino

resulta que yo estoy haciendo un proyecto de huella digital con arduino y el codigo me concede el acceso que la huella todo el tiempo, hasta sin ponerle la huella en vez de denegarlo y necesito ayuda con eso

```
  Serial.println(F("Reading sensor parameters"));
  finger.getParameters();
  Serial.print(F("Status: 0x")); Serial.println(finger.status_reg, HEX);
  Serial.print(F("Sys ID: 0x")); Serial.println(finger.system_id, HEX);
  Serial.print(F("Capacity: ")); Serial.println(finger.capacity);
  Serial.print(F("Security level: ")); Serial.println(finger.security_level);
  Serial.print(F("Device address: ")); Serial.println(finger.device_addr, HEX);
  Serial.print(F("Packet len: ")); Serial.println(finger.packet_len);
  Serial.print(F("Baud rate: ")); Serial.println(finger.baud_rate); 


}

void loop() 
{

  if (finger.verifyPassword())
  {

    Serial.println("Acceso Concedido");    

    digitalWrite(ledRed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledGreen, HIGH);

    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(ledGreen, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledRed, HIGH);    
  }  
  else  
  {

    Serial.println("Acceso Denegado");

    digitalWrite(ledGreen, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledRed, HIGH);    

    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(ledGreen, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledRed, LOW);

  }
}
```

yo creeria que el error esta en esta parte del codigo pero no estoy seguro

```
void loop() 
{

  if (finger.verifyPassword())
```

Comment: ¿Qué librería usas para `finger`?